# Is it spam when sending business advertisement through contact form

Tags: spam, contact-page

I have a question because I like to do things legitimately and dont want any issues down the road, Is it spam when sending business advertisement through contact form. It is in regards to sending opportunity to purchase a domain name that is directly in line with their business.

Answer (score 2):

**If you're having to ask this question then the likelihood... you're sending spam.**

Spam is unsolicited or undesired electronic messages! Spam laws vary from country to country, therefore, you will need to do your own research and find out what legally is allowed and not allowed.

Most countries will not allow SPAM using ANY digital method... in the UK you would not be allowed to use contact forms on a large scale.

***For example in the UK we have:***

> Source: [UK GOV](https://www.gov.uk/marketing-advertising-law/direct-marketing)
>
> **Direct marketing**
>
> You must check if customers want to be contacted by fax, phone, post
>   or email, and give them the chance to object. You must be able to
>   prove you’ve done this.
>
> When you collect customer details, you must get their permission if
>   you want to send them other offers or promotions.
>
> You must also ask for their permission if you want to share their
>   information with another organisation.
>
> SOURCE: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam).
>
> Spam or SPAM may refer to:
>
> - [Spamming](/wiki/Spamming),
>     unsolicited or undesired electronic messages
>
>   - Email spam,
>       unsolicited, undesired, or illegal email messages
>   - Messaging spam,
>       spam targeting users of instant messaging (IM) services, sms or
>       private messages within websites
> - Spam (food), a canned
>     pork meat product

Comment: Thanks for the response and you are right about the UK they seem to be really trying to put an end to spam. I did do research and unfortunately using the search as I have in the title nothing comes up with that answer, everything but. 

I have read the  CAN-SPAM info and sending emails are allowed to businesses as long as certain things are adhered to.

My question was due to mainly look at the fact that someone putting a contact form on a site is actually inviting contact from others but since this is not what they are hoping for I wasn't sure what the rules are.

Comment: Just found the answer I was hoping for:
https://www.avvo.com/legal-answers/does-it-violate-the-can-spam-act-for-a-business-to-1899554.html